# Código HTML erro Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, pessoal. Não entendo muito de programação, peguei um código e desenvolvi um pouco de acordo com o que eu desejava, mas o hyperlink de cada entrada não funciona, tentei várias maneiras de resolver, porém nada funcionou até agora. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Menu */
.sidepanel {
    height: 290px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

/* Menu Cor */
.sidepanel a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
     font-family: Arial;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Menu MouseOver Cor */
.sidepanel a:hover {
    color: #A1A1A1;
}

/* Posição e Cor do botão FecharMenu */
.sidepanel .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 70;
    height: 270;
}

/* Estilo e Botão que abre Menu */
.openbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,40%,0.74);
    margin-top: 110;
    margin-left: 5;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
    background-color: #00F832;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body bgcolor="747474">
<div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
  <a href="" class="closebtn" onMouseOut="closeNav()"></a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Resumo</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Loja</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/CAG/CAG.px">CAG</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Fancoils</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Ventilador</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Energia</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Nobreak</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Gerador</a>
  <a href="local:|foxs:|file:^px/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.px">Intrusão</a>
</div>
<button class="openbtn" onMouseOver="openNav()"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAFxSURBVGhD7dk9L0RBGIbhFRGJQkKjQUJFR0VHSamlV+v9AD9ArdZSUtJRUelUCo1CohCf97ObTTab/ThnzjjzvjJPciW7292VmdHIy8vLK7I5HLQ++t48fnDY/OZ47RA50g9e1xkixxiBu3WHyAlG4Wq9QuQUY3CzfiFyjnG42KAQucQEzG9YiFxjEqZXJERuMQ2zKxoi95iByZUJkQfoWGNuZUPkEYswtZAQecIyzCw0RJ6xChOrEiIvWEfyVQ2RV2wi6WKEyBu2kWyxQuQdO0iymCHyiT3Uvtgh8oVd1Lq/CNFf/1nUutghd0hyHosZcoNkJ+RYIVdIemeJEXKB5LfIqiFnMHGvrxJi6qUlNMTc21dIiMnXyLIhZt+Hy4SYfrEvEvIN8/9DGRai0+w+zG9QyAeSHMlD1i8k6SUpZL1CdG3dgqt1h+ghYQPu1hmip501uFw7RI9tK/rB6xSi58+l5jfHm8JC62Ne3j9co/ELbozEkvc5aZEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="max-width="20px" width="18px"></button> 
<script>
function openNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "100px";
}
function closeNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jovem vc quer que clique aonde para fechar o sidebar?

Comment: Quero que o sidepanel feche sozinho quando o mouse não estiver mais sob ele.

Comment: Cara mas aqui parece que ele está funcionando normal... https://imgur.com/6JqlUr9

Comment: Só parece mesmo. Consegui descobrir o que era. O OnMouseOut estava formatado do mesmo tamanho do Sidepanel sobrepondo o acesso aos links. Assim não deixava clicar em nenhum deles, reformatei para ficar ao lado do Sidepanel, assim funciona. Toda vez que o mouse sair do foco ele fecha sozinho. Obrigado de qualquer forma, Hugo! Tô aprendendo a programar agora.

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando algo meio estranho no `href`, tente colocar o endereço, por exemplo, vamos supor que seu site seja `https://example.com` e você tenha a página do ventilador, você faria algo assim

`<a href="https://example.com/BRASIL/SP/291/Ventilador/Ventilador.html">Ventilador</a>`

Relembrando, no `href` coloque o link completo.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Esse código vai dentro de um sistema supervisório, o link para navegação é esse mesmo. O problema é que o MouseOver para fechar o Sidepanel não deixa o link funcionar. Talvez funcionaria com algum código dentro do <script> para fechar o Sidepanel. Mas eu não consegui fazer rodar sequer algum.